# How to change function data to vector in r

Tags: r

```
xmin = as.integer(readline("Input the left boundary of the period: "))
xmax = readline("Input the right boundary of the period: ")
step = readline("Input the step of the sequence: ")

new.function = function(xmin, xmax, step) {
  while (xmin<=xmax) {
    y = (5 + log(xmin) * exp(xmin) * xmin - (1.5/xmin))
    print(y)
    xmin = as.integer(xmin) + as.integer(step)
  }
}


v <- unlist(new.function(xmin, xmax, step))
print(v)
```

I would like to change the answer to vector, which mean showing all answers in one line
not in 4 consecutive lines. If I input 1, 4, 1 the answer will be 3.5 to 307.1 from top to bottom.
Is it possible to get the answer in one line? (3.5, 14.49341, 70.69865, 307.3814)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the results in a vector instead of printing them:

```
new.function = function(xmin, xmax, step) {
  y <- c() ## Add this to your function
  while (xmin<=xmax) {
    y = c(y, (5 + log(xmin) * exp(xmin) * xmin - (1.5/xmin))) # Modify this
    xmin = as.integer(xmin) + as.integer(step)
  }
  y
}


v <- new.function(xmin, xmax, step)
v
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different from @onyambu answer, just avoiding a growing vector as pointed out in [R inferno](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiMzJLezO36AhW_TTABHfCcBIUQFnoECCEQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.burns-stat.com%2Fpages%2FTutor%2FR_inferno.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3ccYVJrqViLKxffdLT6tdj)

```
new.function = function(xmin, xmax, step) {
  y <- vector(mode="numeric", length=xmax)
  i <- 0
  while (xmin<=xmax) {
    i <- i+1
    y[i] <- (5 + log(xmin) * exp(xmin) * xmin - (1.5/xmin))
    xmin <- as.integer(xmin) + as.integer(step)
  }
  return(y)
}
```

Example:

```
> new.function(1,4,1)
[1]   3.50000  14.49341  70.69865 307.38143
```

Comment: Yes you are right. Did not see that line